# Download PDF file opening as URL in different tab in selenium

Tags: selenium, pdf, selenium-webdriver

**Scenario:**

I have an application, say A: When we log in to A, we have one link say B clicking on which will open a new browser. 
In browser B we have one Link that will open a pdf. Once click on that the PDF is opening as URL in the 2nd tab where we had opened the page A.

**Problem:**

I have tried switching using iteration through window handle but it is not finding that. I have also tried adding below to find all the window handle where you have below locator. 
`if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="plugin"]")))`

but as PDF URL has opened in a 2nd tab, I am not able to get the window handle. I think as per my code below, if I get Window handle then I will use robot class and save the PDF.

**Note** : I am using xframium framework so, had to define 
WebDriver driver = getCustumWebDriver();
I can only use IE/Chrome and no other browsers

Any suggestions on how to solve?

**Code:**

public String getWindowUrl(String saveDir, SoftAssert softAssert, Element element)
{

```
boolean success = false;
String newWindowUrl = null;

try {
    WebDriver driver = getCustumWebDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //current window handle
    String beforWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    _wait(2000);
    //Click on the element to which the pdf link is opened
    _click(element);
    waitForPageLoad();
    _wait(30000);

    Set<String> allWindowhandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String handle1 : allWindowhandles)
    {
        if(!handle1.equals(beforWindowHandle))
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle1);
            _wait(2000);
            newWindowUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            docName = newWindowUrl.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");
            docName = saveDir.concat(docName).concat(".pdf");
            Robot rb = new Robot();

                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                _wait(3000);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

                _wait(1000);

                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
                _wait(3000);

                StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(saveDir);
                Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);

                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                rb.delay(3000);
                // _wait(3000);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                _wait(2000);
    }

    }
    success = true;
    driver.close();
```

}

Scenario 2 : 
I can force the application to open a new browser window just for PDF but I am not able to get to that specific window where new PDF URL will open.
I will try the below and give my observation:

```
**for(String handle1 : allWindowhandles)
            {
             // change focus to new tab
                driver.switchTo().window(handle1);
                if(!(driver.findElement(By.id("Element that will be present on browser window 1 - A ")).isDisplayed()||
                         driver.findElement(By.id("Element that will be present on browser window 2 - B ")).isDisplayed()))
{
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                _wait(3000);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

                _wait(1000);

                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
                _wait(3000);

                StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(saveDir);
                Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);

                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                rb.delay(3000);
                // _wait(3000);
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}**
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217622/how-to-download-pdf-files-using-selenium-java

Comment: New browser or new tab? If it is new tab i can help, also can you access B without going to A?

Comment: @NeaguV- It is opening a new browser pop-up window not new tab

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,Developer of that application that you are referring  has configured the pdf launching in new tab.so we cannot open it in same tab because it has already configured in application label.

Answer (score 0):

Just call this method:

```
public void switchToNEWwindow(){
    try{
        ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(1));
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```